# Change default heading/parts names in lyx

Tags: lyx

I am a new user to Lyx and I am writting my CV in Europass format in Lyx 2.3.2. The default heading "language" displays "other languages". Is there any way to change this heading to "Foreign languages" as the online CV builder shows?
I found this example on lyx forum but not working.
`\renewcommand{\partname}{the name}`

Answer (score 1):

No idea what the online builder is, but if I understand you correctly, go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble, and add

```
\def\ecv@otherlanguageskey{\ecv@utf{Foreign languages}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this was what i wanted.